# I have issue grouping data value by year from mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two columns in mysql tb namely date and value, the db store data value every day, Please I have problem of grouping the value by year.

I tried this sql:

```
$sql = "SELECT value  FROM data GROUP BY  Year(date)";
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
```

But I only get the result of the first day.
Please I want fetch the result like this:

[image: this is how I want the result arrange]

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us more of your code? as opposed to just the `$query`

Comment: $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT day(date), Month(date) FROM data GROUP BY day, Month";
        $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqls);

$sql2 = "SELECT value, Year(date) as year 
                                FROM record 
                                GROUP BY year";
  $query2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql2);

Comment: < ?php
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                                        ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $rows['Month']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $rows['day']; ?></td>

Comment: <?php
                                    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
                                        ?><td><?php echo $row2['value']; ?></td>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                        ?>

Answer (score 0):

Simply try

```
$sql = "SELECT date, value  FROM data GROUP BY  Year(date)";
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data GROUP BY  Year(date)";
```

Also please post rest code to view if any error in rest of code...

Answer (score 0):

You should select the `year` as well and you probably want to do some function on the values you are aggregating, maybe `sum`. Without that you're just going to select one of the values.

```
SELECT value, Year(date) as year 
FROM data 
GROUP BY year
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e1ffe/2